# Change div class based in property of ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm creating a page based in Twitter bootstrap.

In a specific CUD, I need to change a class of a div. `class="tab-pane active"` or `class="tab-pane"` depending the property of my viewmodel.

The property probably is gonna be an int, and then for every div, I will make a verification on active tab. This sounds right?

I thought in something like:

```
<div(@Model.ActiveTab == 1 ? class="tab-pane active" : class="tab-pane")  id="1">
```

but obviously this didn't work

Comment: IS the value of ActiveTab as expected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane @(Model.ActiveTab == 1 ? " active" : "")" id="1">
    ...
</div>
```

or to avoid this horrible tag soup write a custom HTML helper:

```
public static class TabExtensions
{
    private class TabControl: IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ViewContext _viewContext;
        public TabControl(ViewContext viewContext)
        {
            _viewContext = viewContext;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _viewContext.Writer.Write("</div>");
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable Tab(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool active, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        div.AddCssClass("tab-pane");
        if (active)
        {
            div.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(div.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        return new TabControl(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    }
}
```

which could be used like that:

```
@using (Html.Tab(Model.ActiveTab == 1, new { id = "tab1" }))
{
    ...
}
```

and which in this case would emit:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
<div class="@(Model.ActiveTab == 1 ? "tab-pane active" : "tab-pane")"  id="1">
```